# Apollo Client: cache.modify does not work?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I can't seem to get my cache to update after a mutation, although I passed the typename and id to reference the object to modify. What am I doing wrong?
I reproduced a simple example here.

I first initialized my cache with the data -

```
const writeInitialData = () => {
    cache.writeQuery({
        query: gql`
            query {
                test
            }
        `,
        data: {
            test: {
                __typename: 'test',
                id: 'id1',
                string: 'initial string',
            }
        },
    });
};
```

I then executed the mutation on my client.

```
updateTest: (_, __, { cache }) => {
    cache.modify({
      id: cache.identify({
        __typename: 'test',
        id: 'id1',
      }),
      fields: {
        string: 'changed string',
      },
    });
}
```

however, the value in the cache did not change, and furthermore if I console.log() the returned value of cache.modify, it gives me `false`, implying that there is no update to the cache.

Answer (score 3):

in Apollo client v3, you can use new method as `cache.modify`:

```js
 update: (cache, { data }) => {
        // Update cache with modify method
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            authorization(existingAuth = [], { readField }) {
              return existingAuth.filter(
                (rule) =>
                  readField('id', rule) !== data.id,
              );
            },
          },
        });
      },
```

1. authorization is a modifier function.
2. readField is a utility function.
3. _id is an own identifier in the cache.
4. existingAuth is the list of __refs.

**Updated: (31 July 2023)**
I added 3 examples for edit, delete and create operations:

```js
  const [create] = useMutation(CreateProjectDocument);

  const onCreate = (project) => {
    create({
      variables:{
        title: project.title
       },
      update: (cache, { data }) => {
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            getProjects: ({ projects }) => {
              return (projects ?? []).concat({
                id: data?.createProject,
                ...variables,
              });
            },
          },
        });
      },
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

```js
  const [edit] = useMutation(UpdateProjectDocument);

  const onEdit = ({ id, title }: Project) => {
    edit({
      variables:{
        id,
        title
      },
      update: (cache) => {
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            getProjects: ({ projects }, { readField }) => {
              return projects.reduce((prev, cur) => {
                if (readField('id', cur) === id) {
                  return prev.concat({
                    ...variables,
                  });
                }
                return prev.concat(cur);
              }, []);
            },
          },
        });
      },
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

```js
  const [deleteMutation] = useMutation(DeleteProjectDocument);

  const onDelete = (id) => {
    deleteMutation({
      variables: {
        projectId: id,
      },
      update: (cache) => {
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            getProjects: ({ projects }, { readField }) => {
              return projects.filter((item) => readField('id', item) !== id);
            },
          },
        });
      },
    }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `mutation` to update the cache. Try this:

```js
...
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    updateTest: (_, args , { cache }) => {
      const { test } = cache.readQuery({
                query: gql`
                query {
                    test
                }
            `,
            })
      cache.writeData({
          data: {
            test: {...test, args.string}
          },
      })
  }
}

...
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link,
  resolvers,
})
```